# host service checks with no warning/alert at all if host is offline

Tags: nagios

i want to check if some service is available on specific hosts. The problem is that these hosts are volatile, so they are some hours online and other hours offline.

What i have now is host checks (standard group linux server) and service checks (via nrpe-server on the clients). if the host is offline i get a host warning, is there a possibility to prevent any notice and alert on nagios webif if these hosts offline but also to prevent running the service checks if the host offline ?

The only solution i see at the moment is to make no host checks and implement the checks with a concatination from server side of 
 &&

but maybe there is a better solution.

background is to check if on some dhcp clients some infrastructur services are available and when they are failing. so i have no stable hosts here, but also dont want to have warnings at all that these hosts are offline because it is normal !

would be fine if i can do this in a native nagios way

Answer (score 0):

When you execute service checks you can define dependency. If you define if for all probes for particular host to depend of host status this can resolve your problem.
For more information you can check [this page](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/objectdefinitions.html#servicedependency)

Answer (score 0):

This also can help you:

```
# DISABLE SERVICE CHECKS WHEN HOST DOWN
# This option will disable all service checks if the host is not in an UP state
#
# While desirable in some environments, enabling this value can distort report
# values as the expected quantity of checks will not have been performed

host_down_disable_service_checks=1
```